# Define and use new colors for \rowcolor (Colortbl)

Tags: colortbl

How can I use the maroon that I have defined, instead of the gray? Or (better) how can I use directly the maroon from:

```
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
```

---

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage{colortbl}

\definecolor{maroon}{cmyk}{0,0.87,0.68,0.32}

\newcommand{\gray}{\rowcolor[gray]{.90}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|l|c|}
\rowcolor[gray]{.9}
one&two\\
\rowcolor[gray]{.5}
three&four
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: `\rowcolor{maroon}`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle \rowcolor[maroon]{.90} does not work

Comment: That's why I said `\rowcolor{maroon}`. The optional argument of `\color` (or `\rowcolor`) is a _color model_  and if used then the mandatory argumnet takes a color syntax in that model so the `[gray]` model takes a single number. If you don't use the optional argument then it's a color name as defined by `\definecolor`

Answer (score 19, accepted):

For an existing color or one previously defined using `\definecolor` or `\colorlet`, you can use `\rowcolor{maroon}`; if you need shades of the color, you can use the `!<value>` syntax provided by `xcolor` (the `table` option for `xcolor` internally loads `colortbl`):

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

\definecolor{maroon}{cmyk}{0,0.87,0.68,0.32}

\begin{document}

\noindent\begin{tabular}{|l|c|}
\rowcolor{maroon}
one & two \\
\rowcolor{maroon!50}
three & four \\
\rowcolor{maroon!10}
five & six
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Similarly for the `Maroon` color already provided by the `dvipsnames` option:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage[table,dvipsnames]{xcolor}

\begin{document}

\noindent\begin{tabular}{|l|c|}
\rowcolor{Maroon}
one & two \\
\rowcolor{Maroon!50}
three & four \\
\rowcolor{Maroon!10}
five & six
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

The first optional argument for `\rowcolor`  (or `\columncolor`, or `\cellcolor`) behaves like the optional argument for `\color`:

```
\color[<model>]{<color specification>}
```

If the optional argument is used, then the mandatory argument expects a `<colour specification>` instead of a `<name>`.

For a list of available color models (using `xcolor`), see Section 2.2 of the `xcolor` documentation.