# \rowcolor not shading properly

Tags: tables, colortbl

I am using this template for making tables. I tried to add `\rowcolor[gray]{.8}` between `\toprule`s and `\midrule`s but the the effect is bad in the sense that it highlight on 3/4 of the row leaving the edges white.

Any solution?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{colortbl, xcolor}
\usepackage{booktabs,caption,fixltx2e}
\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable}
\begin{document}
\definecolor{lightgray}{rgb}{.9,.9,.9}
\begin{table}
  \begin{threeparttable}
    \caption{Sample ANOVA table}
     \begin{tabular}{lllll}
        \toprule
        Stubhead & \( df \) & \( f \) & \( \eta \) & \( p \) \\
        \midrule
        Row 1    & 1        & 0.67    & 0.55       & 0.41    \\
        Row 2    & 2        & 0.02    & 0.01       & 0.39    \\
        Row 3    & 3        & 0.15    & 0.33       & 0.34    \\
        Row 4    & 4        & 1.00    & 0.76       & 0.54    \\
        \bottomrule
     \end{tabular}
    \begin{tablenotes}
      \small
      \item This is where authors provide additional information about
      the data, including whatever notes are needed.
    \end{tablenotes}
  \end{threeparttable}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: At the beginning of the post there is an "Hi All,". Just wanted to point it out. It is the second time that this happens and it honestly looks like a big impolite.

Comment: Greetings and thanks are assumed: we're quite a friendly community and we trust in newcomers to be as friendly as everybody here. We believe it's simpler to directly state the problem; the better way to thank is upvoting useful answers and accepting the most useful one, provided it solves the problem or leads to a full solution.

Answer (score 4):

I think the problem comes from `booktabs`, which adds some vertical space above and below its rules. This vertical space seems not to be considered as part of the row cells, and hence is not coloured.

A workaround consists in using the `cellspace` package, which defines a minimal vertical vertical space between the top of a row and the above `\hline` and symmetrically a minimal vertical space between the bottom of a row and the below `\hline`. This has more or less the same effect as `\addlinespace` from booktabs, but is taken into consideration when colouring the cells.

Another feature of booktabs, namely horizontal rules of different thicknesses, can be achieved with the `makecell` package, which has an `\Xhline{thickness}` command. So I defined a `\thickhline` command, that has the same thickness as the default for `\top/\bottomrule`s in booktabs (0.08em).

Here is a code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{colortbl, xcolor}
\usepackage{booktabs,caption,fixltx2e}
\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable}

\usepackage{cellspace}
\setlength\cellspacetoplimit{6pt}
\setlength\cellspacebottomlimit{6pt}

\usepackage{makecell} 
\newcommand\thickhline{\Xhline{0.08em}}

\begin{document}
\definecolor{lightgray}{rgb}{.9,.9,.9}
\begin{table}[!ht]
  \begin{threeparttable}
    \caption{Sample ANOVA table}
     \begin{tabular}{*{6}{Sl}}
        %\toprule
\thickhline
 \rowcolor[gray]{.8} Stubhead & \( df \) & \( f \) & \( \eta \) & \( p \) \\
\hline
        Row 1 & 1 & 0.67 & 0.55 & 0.41 \\
        Row 2 & 2 & 0.02 & 0.01 & 0.39 \\
        Row 3 & 3 & 0.15 & 0.33 & 0.34 \\
        Row 4 & 4 & 1.00 & 0.76 & 0.54 \\
\thickhline
     \end{tabular}\smallskip
    \begin{tablenotes}
      \small
      \item This is where authors provide additional information about
      the data, including whatever notes are needed.
    \end{tablenotes}
  \end{threeparttable}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You can use features of `\booktabs`, for instance `\specialrule{\heavyrulewidth}{0pt}{0pt}`.

Comment: But then you don't have any vertical space added, I guess? Which makes ugly tables.

Comment: The second and third arguments are for spaces above and below the rule, respectively. My advice is *not* shading the table header, the heavier rules already show it clearly.

Comment: @egreg: That's another question. The problem remains if you have, say, a table with many rows and want to alternate colours in rows.

Comment: That's a different problem; but in that case the shading need not touch the rules.

Comment: So that it looks like a highlighter?

Comment: Hi, thanks for helping. Fixed :) now it looks great!

Answer (score 1):

Similar to @Bernard answer ... Difference are in use of packages `boldline` and `treepartablex`. Instead of packages `colortbl` and `xcolor` is used only `xcolor` with option `table`. Also it is declared only five columns as they are used in table:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\definecolor{lightgray}{rgb}{.9,.9,.9}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{boldline, cellspace}
\setlength\cellspacetoplimit{4pt}
\setlength\cellspacebottomlimit{4pt}
\usepackage[referable,flushleft]{threeparttablex}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[!ht]
\begin{threeparttable}
\caption{Sample ANOVA table}
\label{tab:my table}
    \begin{tabular}{*{5}{Sl}}
    \hlineB{2}
    \rowcolor[gray]{.8} Stubhead & \( df \) & \( f \) & \( \eta \) & \( p \) \\
    \hlineB{1.5}
Row 1 & 1 & 0.67 & 0.55 & 0.41 \\
Row 2 & 2 & 0.02 & 0.01 & 0.39 \\
Row 3 & 3 & 0.15 & 0.33 & 0.34 \\
Row 4 & 4 & 1.00 & 0.76 & 0.54 \\
    \hlineB{2}
     \end{tabular}
    \begin{tablenotes}\footnotesize
\note This is where authors provide additional information about
      the data, including whatever notes are needed.
    \end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `[table]{colorx}` internally loads `colortbl`... [see here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/112682/97536)

Comment: @MatthiasArras, (i) correct is `[table]{xcolor}` (ii) it load internally `colortbl` (iii) to `colortbl` add some functionality as `\rowcolors` and `\rowcolors*` etc (see *2.12 Color in tables*, page 28 in package documentation), (iv)  I'm very aware what `xcolor` offer, regardless that I didn't mentioned explicitly what you noted in in your comment :-). Anyway, thank you for your comment.

Answer (score 0):

The environment `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix` has tools to color rows (cells, columns, blocks, etc.) in a way compatible with the rules of `booktabs`.

However, in order to use `{NiceTabular}` in `{threeparttable}`, you have first to tell it to `threeparttable` with the dedicated tool.

```
\makeatletter
\AddToHook{env/threeparttable/begin}
    {\TPT@hookin{NiceTabular}\TPT@hookin{NiceTabular*}}
\makeatother
```

Here is the full MWE.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{booktabs,caption}
\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\begin{document}

\makeatletter
\AddToHook{env/threeparttable/begin}
    {\TPT@hookin{NiceTabular}\TPT@hookin{NiceTabular*}}
\makeatother


\begin{table}
  \begin{threeparttable}
    \caption{Sample ANOVA table}
     \begin{NiceTabular}{lllll}
     \CodeBefore
       \rowcolor[gray]{0.8}{1}
     \Body
        \toprule
        Stubhead & \( df \) & \( f \) & \( \eta \) & \( p \) \\
        \midrule
        Row 1    & 1        & 0.67    & 0.55       & 0.41    \\
        Row 2    & 2        & 0.02    & 0.01       & 0.39    \\
        Row 3    & 3        & 0.15    & 0.33       & 0.34    \\
        Row 4    & 4        & 1.00    & 0.76       & 0.54    \\
        \bottomrule
     \end{NiceTabular}
    \begin{tablenotes}
      \small
      \item This is where authors provide additional information about
      the data, including whatever notes are needed.
    \end{tablenotes}
  \end{threeparttable}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

You need several compilations (because `nicematrix` uses PGF/Tikz nodes under the hood).

[image: Output of the above code]