# How to remove blank spaces around table rules

Tags: tables, rules, booktabs, colortbl

I am trying to produce a colored table but the separation lines and the border lines are creating blank spaces that ruins the aesthetics of the table. I wish to remove them.

[image]

Here is the code I'm using

```
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{hhline}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{l*8cl}
\toprule
\rowcolor[HTML]{A4CAF6} 
\multicolumn{1}{c}{\cellcolor[HTML]{A4CAF6}}                            & \multicolumn{8}{c}{\cellcolor[HTML]{A4CAF6}Temperatura $[^{\circ}C]$} & \cellcolor[HTML]{A4CAF6}                             \\ \cmidrule(lr){2-9}
\rowcolor[HTML]{A4CAF6} 
\multicolumn{1}{c}{\multirow{-2}{*}{\cellcolor[HTML]{A4CAF6}Propiedad}} & 25     & 50     & 100     & 150    & 200    & 250    & 300    & 350    & \multirow{-2}{*}{\cellcolor[HTML]{A4CAF6}Referencia} \\
\rowcolor[HTML]{FFFFC7} 
$Rp_{0,2} [MPa]$                                                          &        &        &         &        &        &        &        &        &                                                      \\ 
\rowcolor[HTML]{CFCFCF} 
$UTS [MPa]$                                                               &        &        &         &        &        &        &        &        &                                                      \\ \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Use `\hline`  instead of `\toprule` and `\bottomrule` and `\hhline{~--------~}` instead of `\cmidrule`.

Comment: See also: [Problems with \rowcolors and booktabs](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/209574/134144), [Booktabs and colortbl not filling height of row](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/266438/134144) and [\rowcolor not shading properly](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/190945/134144)

Comment: Side note: You might want to add `\usepackage{siunitx}` and use `[\si{\celsius}]` instead of `$[^{\circ}C]$`.

Comment: I stopped using `\hline` because it didn't show when extracted to a pdf. Although I did use `\hhline` as you sagguested but the problem persists. It generates a white line of the same width.

Comment: `\hhline{>{\arrayrulecolor[HTML]{A4CAF6}}->{\arrayrulecolor{black}}-------->{\arrayrulecolor[HTML]{A4CAF6}}->{\arrayrulecolor{black}}}` should remove the small white gap

Comment: It works! Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

With the lastest version of `nicematrix` (4.0 of 2020/05/08), you can have the result easily (you need several compilations).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\usepackage{nicematrix}

\definecolor{myblue}{HTML}{A4CAF6}
\definecolor{myyellow}{HTML}{FFFFC7}
\definecolor{mygray}{HTML}{CFCFCF}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\begin{NiceTabular}{L*{8}{C}L}[code-before = \rowcolor{myblue}{1,2} \rowcolor{myyellow}{3} \rowcolor{mygray}{4}]
\toprule
\multirow{2}{*}{Propiedad} & \multicolumn{8}{C}{Temperatura [\si{\celsius}]} & \multirow{2}{*}{Referencia}\\
\cmidrule{2-9}
 & 25 & 50 & 100 & 150 & 200 & 250 & 300 & 350 \\
R\textsubscript{p0,2} [\si{\mega\pascal}] \\
UTS [\si{\mega\pascal}] \\
\bottomrule
\end{NiceTabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image: Result of the above code]

Comment: Nice new features of `nicematrix`. A question: is possible to add more vertical space to table cells ( I steal read new documentation)? +1!

Comment: I assume you bother about the yellow gray rows. It's possible to use `\extrarowheight` and `\arraystretch` as usual. However, in this case, these parameters would also affect the blue zone which is perfect. It's possible to use `\\[...]` as usual but such a tuning beetween the yellow row and the gray one would increase the depth of the yellow row and not the height of the gray one. Eventually, I don't see other mean than adding manual struts in the yellow and  gray rows...

Comment: Francly said, I hope that there is way to use for example `cellspace`. I will make some more test late evening.

Comment: In this answer, since version 5.0 of `nicematrix` one must write `l*{8}{c}l` instead of `L*{8}{C}L` in the preamble of  `{NiceTabular}` (but there is an option for backward compatibility).

Answer (score 0):

Here is my suggestion. In order to get rid of the white line, you can use `\hhline{>{\arrayrulecolor[HTML]{A4CAF6}}->{\arrayrulecolor{black}}-------->{\arrayrulecolor[HTML]{A4CAF6}}->{\arrayrulecolor{black}}}`. This will fill the white gap with a line in the same color as the background.

Instead of repeating the HTML color definition over and over, I suggest defining the color in the preamble and using this predefined color throughout your document. This will make thing much easier if you later on decide to change the color. You will then only have to chenge the definition in the preamble instead of changing the color of every single cell. 
In the following MWE I have used such a globally defined color.

I have also added the `siunitx` package for the units °C and MPa. I have also changed the code for Rp0,2 and UTS (assuming that these correpsond to yield strength and ultimate tensile strength) since using math mode for abbreviations is not recommended. If you want UTS to show up in italic, use `\textit{UTS}` instead.

For the second table, I have added the `cellspace` packagein order to add some vertical space above and below the text in each cell to avoid overlap with the horizontal lines.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{hhline}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\definecolor{myblue}{HTML}{A4CAF6}
\definecolor{myyellow}{HTML}{FFFFC7}
\definecolor{mygray}{HTML}{CFCFCF}

\usepackage[column=0]{cellspace}
\setlength\cellspacetoplimit{0.5\tabcolsep}
\setlength\cellspacebottomlimit{\cellspacetoplimit}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{l*8cl}
\hline
\rowcolor[HTML]{A4CAF6} 
\multicolumn{1}{c}{\cellcolor{myblue}}                            & \multicolumn{8}{c}{\cellcolor{myblue}Temperatura [\si{\celsius}]} & \cellcolor{myblue}                             \\ 
\hhline{>{\arrayrulecolor{myblue}}->{\arrayrulecolor{black}}-------->{\arrayrulecolor{myblue}}->{\arrayrulecolor{black}}}
\rowcolor{myblue} 
\multicolumn{1}{c}{\multirow{-2}{*}{\cellcolor{myblue}Propiedad}} & 25     & 50     & 100     & 150    & 200    & 250    & 300    & 350    & \multirow{-2}{*}{\cellcolor{myblue}Referencia} \\
\rowcolor{myyellow} 
R\textsubscript{p0,2} [\si{\mega\pascal}]                                                          &        &        &         &        &        &        &        &        &                                                      \\ 
\rowcolor{mygray} 
UTS [\si{\mega\pascal}]                                                               &        &        &         &        &        &        &        &        &                                                      \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}


\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{0l*{8}{0c}0l}
\hline
\rowcolor[HTML]{A4CAF6} 
\multicolumn{1}{c}{\cellcolor{myblue}}                            & \multicolumn{8}{c}{\cellcolor{myblue}Temperatura [\si{\celsius}]} & \cellcolor{myblue}                             \\ 
\hhline{>{\arrayrulecolor{myblue}}->{\arrayrulecolor{black}}-------->{\arrayrulecolor{myblue}}->{\arrayrulecolor{black}}}
\rowcolor{myblue} 
\multicolumn{1}{c}{\multirow{-2}{*}{\cellcolor{myblue}Propiedad}} & 25     & 50     & 100     & 150    & 200    & 250    & 300    & 350    & \multirow{-2}{*}{\cellcolor{myblue}Referencia} \\
\rowcolor{myyellow} 
R\textsubscript{p0,2} [\si{\mega\pascal}]                                                          &        &        &         &        &        &        &        &        &                                                      \\ 
\rowcolor{mygray} 
UTS [\si{\mega\pascal}]                                                               &        &        &         &        &        &        &        &        &                                                      \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```