# using self-defined colors with the colortbl package

Tags: color, colortbl

If I want to use predefined colors to color rows with the `colortbl` package, it doesn't work:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{colortbl}

\definecolor{anti-flashwhite}{rgb}{0.95, 0.95, 0.96}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{c|c}
     \rowcolor[anti-flashwhite]{0.5}Eins & Zwei  \\
     \rowcolor[gray]{0.5}Drei & Vier
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Any ideas how to make it work?

Comment: `\rowcolor{anti-flashwhite}{0.5}` the optional argument would correspond to a color model such as rgb, cmyk or gray. Hence the error message `Package xcolor Error: Undefined color model anti-flashwhite.` that you will get from your code.

Comment: Instead of `xcolor`, `color` and `colortbl` you only need `\usepackage[table]{xcolor}`.

Comment: @leandriis `\usepackage[table]{xcolor}` still doesn't work for me. Same error message `Package xcolor Error: Undefined color model anti-flashwhite.`

Comment: `anti-flashwhite` must be placed in a set of `{}` instead of `[]` when used with the `\rowcolor` command. The remark about the packages was more a side note than actually related to the error message itself.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/112671/define-and-use-new-colors-for-rowcolor-colortbl?rq=1